# Can't send complex types to WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, monomac

I have a working C# Web Service running on IIS on a dedicated server. There is a method that gets `Session` object(`DataContract`) and its tested and working on Windows clients. However now I'm developing a "Xamarin.Mac" application and I need to connect to server , but I'm facing a specific error.

```
[DataContract]
public class Session{

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ComputerHash { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Session` class I'm trying to send.

```
[OperationContract]
bool Login ( Session session );
```

And this is the method I'm calling.

But when I'm debugging, I checked that my `Session` object is filled and the values are set. But server gets the `Session` object but all fields of the object are set to null. Thus it gives me null exception.

Interestingly non-complex objects are being sent without any problem, but these complex types are giving me headaches.

What I might be missing here?

Comment: Since this is on IIS and Session is a class built-in for handling the user session, have you tried using a different name for your custom class?
Also, what is the network traffic, it is possible that the client does not send a properly formatted object at all, so the issue may be in the client, not in your service

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you're making the request. You need to "post" the data to the server. The data needs to be defined in the body of the message, not as parameters in the request url.

Comment: I make calls through service reference not via native http requests.

Comment: I don't know if his answer is correct, but depending on how the endpoint is configured, it is likely using http requests, so the fact that you are using a service reference doesn't invalidate his suggestion; you should look at the network traffic and verify.